# How to execute a task in background with angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

Whenever I click on a row of an HTML table I'm just calling a function that navigates to a specific URL. On that URL there is a service that opens a new browser tab and download a pdf file generated from the HTML of the page using the html2pdf library.

```
//function called on click event from html table:
pdfExport(): void {
  this.router.navigate(['/ViewForPdf/'],{queryParams:{ id:this.id, dist:this.dist}});
}
```

After navigating to the new URL I call the htmlToPdf function which generates a pdf from the URL where I am right now.

```
//function that generate the pdf from the html
htmlToPdf(): void {
    const element = document.getElementById('viewForPdf');

    const opt = {
      filename: 'segnaler.pdf',
      margin: 5
    };

    html2pdf().set(opt).from(element).save();
}
```

Is there a way to make all this process work in the background without the user seeing a new browser tab opening but only the pdf being downloaded after the function has been called?

Comment: Take a look at Angular Web Workers https://angular.io/guide/web-worker.

Comment: or just use await, if you do not want to block the gui.

Comment: -> Use PDF -component as child component
-> On the click of row of HTML table,
 Pass the **id** and **dist** as input parameter of child component.
-> In the child component, detect the change of Input() values in (**ngOnChanges**) function ,fire the print PDF function.